# scalaz-stream how to implement `ask-then-wait-reply` tcp client

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

I want to implement an client app that first send an request to server then wait for its reply(similar to http)

My client process may be

```
 val topic = async.topic[ByteVector]
 val client = topic.subscribe
```

Here is the api

```
trait Client {
  val incoming = tcp.connect(...)(client)
   val reqBus = topic.pubsh()
   def ask(req: ByteVector): Task[Throwable \/ ByteVector] =  {
      (tcp.writes(req).flatMap(_ => tcp.reads(1024))).to(reqBus)
      ???
   }
}
```

Then, how to implement the remain part of `ask`  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, the implementation is done with publishing the message via sink and then awaiting some sort of reply on some source, like your topic.

Actually we have a lot of idioms of this in our code :

```
def reqRply[I,O,O2](src:Process[Task,I],sink:Sink[Task,I],reply:Process[Task,O])(pf: PartialFunction[O,O2]):Process[Task,O2] = {
 merge.mergeN(Process(reply, (src to sink).drain)).collectFirst(pf)
}
```

Essentially this first hooks to reply stream to await any resulting `O` confirming our request sent. Then we publish message `I` and consult `pf` for any incoming `O` to be eventually translated to `O2` and then terminate.

Comment: is `TSource[O2]` the same as `Process1[O, O2]`?

Comment: Actually not, it is type alias from our code base for `Process[Task,O2]`, sorry for confusion.

Comment: Ah, thanks @pavel :) It would be nice to see some more examples like this one used in the wild :) Adding examples of common patterns to the scalaz-stream wiki would help us that are new to the library :)